# Homomorphism between free groups

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $F_a$ be the group which is freely generated by $a$ elements. How to show that there is a homomorphism from $F_a$ onto $F_b$ if and only if $b\le a$?

I was thinking one possibility is if $F_a$ generated freely by $\{x_1, \dots , x_a\}$ and $F_b$ generated freely by $\{y_1, \dots , y_b\}$ then consider map which says $\phi(x_i)=y_i$ for $1\le i \le b$ and $y_1$ otherwise. I do not know if this works or even how to proceed. How to show this fact?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\;n=a<b\;$ and further suppose $\;\phi:F_a\to F_b\;$ is an epimorphism.

So $\;\phi(F_a)=F_b\implies  F_b=\langle\,\phi(x_1),..,\phi(x_n)\,\rangle\;$, which of course is impossible as $\;F_b\;$ cannot be generated, free or not, by less than $\;b\;$ elements

Comment: you're just re stating the question differently

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $f : F_a \to F_b$ be a surjective homomorphism. Look at $F_a / ker(f) \simeq F_b$. What do you know about the generators of the quotient?

Answer (score 0):

Your map works! Just check that it is indeed a homomorphism and surjective.

For the other direction, argue by contradiction. A homomorphism is surjective iff its surjective on the generators. If $a<b$ then $F_b$ is generated by $(\phi(x_j))_{j=1}^a$. Contradiction!

Comment: I think showing surjectivity is straighforward..but how to show it is a homomorphism?

Comment: Show $\phi(xx') = \phi(x)\phi(x')$ for reduced words $x,x'$. The reduced words are just finite strings of the $x_j's$.

Comment: What do you mean by "surjective on the generators"? E.g., how does it apply to the endomorphism on the free group on $\{x, y\}$ that maps $x$ to $x$ and $y$ to $xy$?

Comment: GiantTortoise1729 hasn't been seen in over four years, @RobArthan :(